# How to solve this Tamil (Indian) Language issue in Opencart 2?

Tags: php, opencart, cart, tamil

I'm using opencart 2.0.3.1, and added Tamil (one of Indian) Language as optional second language (for visitors) by:

System > Localisation > Languages

with following values:

- Name: Tamil
- Code: ta
- Locale: ta_IN.UTF-8,ta_IN,ta-in,tamil
- Image: in.png
- Directory: tamil
- Status: Enabled
- Sort Order: 2

Correct me if any wrong values.

And, have created a clone of:

- catalog/language/english

and replaced the variable values with Tamil words.

And more, has tried renaming the PHP file (which was as "english.php"):

- catalog/language/tamil/tamil.php
- catalog/language/tamil/default.php

But no use!

Categories, Product Name, Description, (user given values) are shown in Tamil.

But button captions, labels, etc., (programmatic variables/values) displayed as:

- "button_cart"
- "button_cancel"
- "text_select"
- "text_loading"
- ...

How to solve this and a complete workable Tamil language pack?

Comment: Open tamil.php (`catalog/language/tamil/tamil.php`) file. then change `$_['code']                  = 'ta';` instead of `$_['code']                  = 'en';` & then check it.

Comment: Thanks! But, I already changed it. But no use!

Answer (score 3):

I have try your code with setup new language. So, It is working fine.

**1** Go to **catalog/language/**

Copy & paste english language folder & then rename it new folder name to tamil.

**2** Go to **catalog/language/tamil**

change file name `tamil.php` instead of `english.php`

**3** Go to **catalog/language/tamil/tamil.php**

Open tamil.php file. then change `$_['code'] = 'ta';` instead of `$_['code'] = 'en';`

**4** Go to **admin/language/**

Follow above 3 steps same as for admin language.

**5** Go to admin > **System > Localisation > Languages** > & then setup following value.

1. Name: Tamil
2. Code: ta
3. Locale: ta_IN.UTF-8,ta_IN,ta-in,tamil
4. Image: in.png
5. Directory: tamil
6. Status: Enabled
7. Sort Order: 2

**6** Go to admin > **Extensions > Modifications** and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system.
& then check it.

Comment: Maybe cache issue. Please Go to admin > Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system. then check it.

Comment: I have update answer. hope, you will accept. Thanks.